# Buying advice: 744t with a mixpre or a SQN4S-II as extra pre-amp ? 

Tags: sound-devices, purchase-advice, 744t

Hi All,

I already own a SQN4S-II with a PCM-D50, but would love to record 4 track.
Right now I'm in the position of buying a second hand 744 for a reasonable price, including a MixPre and a CL1+MiniKeyboard.

I was only looking for a 744t, so I was wondering if the MixPre is the best match for the SD? It's smaller and is from the same company, but wouldn't my SQN4 suffice?
On the other hand, I could always sell the MixPre.

@Tim Prebble: you combine a 302 with your 744, does this have advantages I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of taste really both aesthetically and intellectually as well as the types of recording setups you plan to use. Using the awesome SQN preamps is absolutely fine. However one advantage with the MixPre is that its preamps matches the ones on the 744t's ch 1 and 2. Say that you want to record a nice quad ambiance with 4 identical mics, then ch 3 and 4 will likely have a differently "coloured" sound (frequency nuances + hiss level) compared to ch 1 and 2.

So in short - without going into different mic types and positioning you should try the setups out with your ears and choose which you like most. And if budget allows it a MixPre is never a bad thing to have laying around it could be used as a new front end to the D50, which is a sweet portable stealth setup.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-amps on the mix-pre are close, but they are not the same. I actually prefer them to the 7-Series recorders. They feature lundahl input transformers and the mix-pre also has an optical limiter which is quite nice. I can't say that I'm a huge fan of the 7-series limiters. They do the job, but the mix-pre's limiter is quite warm adds a mid-range creamy-ness to things. I don't think you'll run into any hiss issues with the mix-pre, it is also a damn quiet unit. And don't confuse the mix-pre and mix-pre-d. The mix-pre-d is a totally different unit and not an improvement in my opinion.

I would say play around with the tools you have. All of them will come in handy. I would also not sell the mix-pre. It is a great compact unit that sadly has been discontinued. In its place is something inferior.